# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ Kotlin Retrofit Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

For days I have had this problem that I cannot solve since it always gives me an error when loading the data from the api, Help my problem its:

FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

**VIEW MODEL**

```
@HiltViewModel

class RMViewModel @Inject constructor(private val useCase: RMGetCharacterUseCase) : ViewModel() {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow<RMListState>(RMListState.Empty)
    val state: StateFlow<RMListState> = _state

    init {
        getAllCharacters()
    }
    private fun getAllCharacters()=viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            _state.value = RMListState.Loading
            val data = useCase.invoke()
            if (data.data.isNullOrEmpty()) _state.value = RMListState.Fail(data.message ?: "An unexpected error occured")
            else _state.value = RMListState.Success(data.data ?: emptyList())
    }
}
```

**USE CASE**

```
class RMGetCharacterUseCase @Inject constructor(private val repo: RMRepository) {
    suspend operator fun invoke(): Validator {
        try {
            val bundle = repo.getCharacters().map { it.toDomain() }
            return if (bundle.isNullOrEmpty()) Validator("FALLO")
            else Validator("retorno", bundle)
        }catch (e: HttpException) {
            return Validator(e.localizedMessage ?: "An unexpected error occured")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            return Validator("Couldn't reach server. Check your internet connection.")
        }
    }
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
class RMRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(private val api: RMApiService):RMRepository{
    override suspend fun getCharacters(): List<Result> = api.getCharacters()
}
```

**API**

```
interface RMApiService {
    @GET(Constants.END_POINT)
    suspend fun getCharacters():List<Result>
}
```

**DATA**

```
data class Result(
    val created: String?,
    val episode: List<String?>?,
    val gender: String?,
    val id: Int?,
    val image: String?,
    val name: String?,
    val species: String?,
    val status: String?,
    val type: String?,
    val url: String?
)
```

**DATA DOMAIN**

```
data class RM(
    val created: String?,
    val episode: List<String?>?,
    val gender: String?,
    val id: Int?,
    val image: String?,
    val name: String?,
    val species: String?,
    val status: String?,
    val type: String?,
    val url: String?
)

fun Result.toDomain()= RM(
    created=created,
    episode=episode,
    gender=gender,
    id=id,
    image=image,
    name=name,
    species=species,
    status=status,
    type=type,
    url=url
)
```

Comment: The error means that your JSON does not match your classes. For example, the endpoint might be returning an object instead of a `List<Result>`, or `episode` might be an object instead of a `List<String?>`. You might consider editing your question and providing a sample of the JSON that is returned by the endpoint.

Comment: "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY" means you were trying to return a List<X> type from a JSON list string (`[...]`), and "but was BEGIN_OBJECT" means it actually got an object string (`{...}`)

Answer (score 0):

Try to return `Result` object instead of `List<Result>`:

```
interface RMApiService {
    @GET(Constants.END_POINT)
    suspend fun getCharacters(): Result
}
```